# PHP-FPM wont start from a Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

Hello dear community,

I am trying to accomplish something very simple, **I want to start a php-fpm service from a docker container using a dockerfile**. My dockerfile content is posted here below:

```
   FROM debian
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install php -y && apt-get install php7.3-fpm -y && service php7.3-fpm start
```

When I build this image from the dockerfile and run it as a container, the php-fpm service is not active.

I even tried it with using docker's "interactive mode" (-i arg) to ensure that the container was not  exiting in the case that the service was running as a daemon.

I am confused because the command  `RUN service php7.3-fpm start` from my dockerfile should have started the service.

To successfully start the service inside my container I actually  have to manually log into it using the command `docker exec -it #containerID bash` and run the command `service php7.3-fpm start` myself, and then the service works and becomes active.

I don't understand why the php-fpm service is not starting automatically from my Dockerfile, any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To a first approximation, commands like `service` don't work in Docker at all.

A Docker container runs only a single foreground process.  That's not usually an init system, or if it is, it's just enough to handle some chores like zombie process cleanup.  Conversely, a Docker image only contains a filesystem image and some metadata on how to start that process, but it does not persist any running processes.  So for example if you

```
RUN service php7.3-fpm start
```

it might record in some file that the service was supposed to have been started, but once the `RUN` command completes, the running process doesn't exist at all any more.

The easiest way to get a running PHP-FPM setup is to use the [Docker Hub `php` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/):

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
```

This should do all of the required setup, including arranging for the FPM server to run as the main container command; you just need to `COPY` your application code in.

If you really want to run it yourself, you need to make it be the main command of your custom image

```
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

as is done in [`php:7.3-fpm`'s Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/424dbd51d6699f2432f68f22cc2a910672a7bdfd/7.3/buster/fpm/Dockerfile#L260).

Comment: Surely there's a simple way to just get the service to start with the machine, without switching to a whole new image or a custom startup script.